# Adding HTML table related controls on RTE toolbar

Tags: crafter-cms

We want to be able to add and update HTML tables for our rich text using a Rich text editor. We need a button(or buttons) providing us the

1. Ability to add HTML table. On click of the button, user should be
   able to specify the number of rows and columns in the table
2. Ability to add columns to existing table
3. Ability to remove columns from existing table
4. Ability to add rows to existing table
5. Ability to remove rows from existing table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an admin user, in Crafter Studio go to the "Administration" panel for a given site.  There you will find a tool called "Configurations."  Using this tool, select RTE Configuration. This will load the RTE configuration for the site.  This is where you will make your updates.

The RTE configuration file allows you to define "setups."  Each setup has a name (the default one is called 'generic'.)  An RTE can be assigned a given setup.

Each setup has tags for toolbar configuration called toolbar1, toolbar2, toolbar3, and toolbar4.  This is where you configure the buttons available to the RTE.  The possible options are listed here: https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x//reference/buttons/

The button names you are looking for are:
table
tablecontrols
row_props
cell_props
delete_col
delete_row
col_after
col_before
row_after
row_before
split_cells
merge_cells